# It's possible to have multiple access log files, in Apache Tomcat, filtered by connectors?

Tags: java, tomcat, connector, access-log, server.xml

In my Tomcat 'server.xml' I have a single service with two connectors for the same webapp:

- the first listening on port 8080 with the "HTTP/1.1" protocol;
- the second listening on port 8009 with the "AJP/1.3" protocol.

Is it possible to configure two access log files (org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve), one logging the requests made to the connector on the **8080** port and one for the requests to the connector listening on the **8009** port?

I have already made it configure two services (with only one connector each), but this "solution" means that the same webapp is running twice at the same time, causing all sort of problems.